# What category should you use for the Facebook page of an online music store?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I run an online record shop, and I have a Facebook page for it that I update rarely.
I noticed that it is in a generic category Companies & Organizations > Company,
and I'd like to put it into something more apt.  However, there really isn't another clear choice.

There is no music shop choice under local businesses, companies, or music.

Any suggestions, or answers about how I can get fb to add the right category?

Answer (score 1):

What about using the `Entertainment` category and then selecting `Record Label` ?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not really accurate, although a reasonable idea.